# Help installing MavensMate IDe for Salesforce

Tags: ide, mavensmate

To begin with, I downloaded Git, then I loaded Sublime Text 3 Windows 64 bit, when I try to download MavensMate.exe file, I got the following error -

[image]

After dabbling with the mavensmate installer, I finally got to the point where I could see the ability to create a new project. however this is the error I get when trying to create new project

[image]

As suggested in the error installed the latest version of mm by going to MavensMate > MavensMate API (mm) version...

Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen this before. I'd suggest uninstalling sublime 3 and doing a clean re-install. Also, are you the administrator on the machine you are installing this on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing via the Sublime Text Package Control?
http://mavensmate.com/Getting_Started/Users

Comment: I got past the error. However when I go to MavesMate > Project > New Project nothing happens. I was expecting a webpage to open. I do have Chrome as my browser. and i have set the absolute location where I want my  MavensMate project to reside"mm_workspace" : "/Users/<username>/Documents/workspaces/mavensmate",                                                                    any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, so after dabbling with the mavensmate installer, I finally got to the point where I could see the ability to create a new project. however this is the error I get when trying to create new project

Comment: Which error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This website helped me install MavensMate with Sublime Text 3.

https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-mavensmate-sublime-text-apex-development/

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here:
https://vishnuvaishnav.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/how-to-setup-mavensmate-in-sublime-text-for-salesforce/
In the blog please see Point:
F. Setup Directories :
1. Go on MavensMate > Settings > User.
2. Go on MavensMate > Settings > Default.
3. We have to setup dir in both files.
Find out “mm_workspace” : “”,
Put you dir here like if your dir is E:\ST then type it will be :
“mm_workspace” : “E://ST”,
Do same things for both files and save both files.

The issue is you are not setting your workspace dir. So sublime is not finding a place to store data.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Can you please post the exact cause on the answer instead of pasting the link to your blog.?